# CSS3: rotate a image in different axis

Tags: css, rotation

It's like a leaning book on some shelf , with its front-cover towards you , looks like the "iBook" app in Macintosh , but the books are slightly leaned.

So it's neither rotating by X or Y axis , is that possible with HTML5 ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out css3 [2d transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-functions) and [3d transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-3d-transforms/#transform-functions). They are *not* html5 in strict sense, but i suppose that is what you actually want ...